# How do I Copy spreadsheet formats while updating a given cell with a counter in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

The project I am working on is the creation of a macro in Excel that copies the format from a given tab and duplicates it into subsequent tabs.

Just as a heads up, this is my first exposure to VBA but I do have some experience with C++

I have already found a good template to work with for the above that does the task well enough and is as follows:

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRenameByCell()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

    If wks.Range("H9").Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = wks.Range("H9").Value
    End If

    wks.Active
End Sub
```

The problem I am trying to solve at this point is integrating a line of code that acts as a counter which updates the value of the given cell by +1 with every new sheet and references the updated cell for the sheet label.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Does H9 just contain a numeric value?  What do your sheet names look like?

Comment: Just a blank master template at this point.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for. "updates the value of the given cell by +1" do you mean the value of `wks.Range("H9")`? And if so, is the activesheet we are talking about the initial active one, or the new one? Is `ActiveSheet.Name =` trying to rename the old or the new sheet? Isn't `Sheets.Count` enough of a counter, or do you need a different way of counting?

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I am still familiarizing myself with the VBA syntax. My goal it to provide a function similar in effect to "i++" that is aimed at the specific cell, "H9," which has the trigger of the creation of a new sheet via the macro. The creation of a new sheet isn't an issue, the only thing I'm banging my head against the wall about at this point is the desired counter function, which would start at a base value of 1.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I will toy with that tomorrow when I am back at the office. Digging a little deeper I found that there are no operation-assignment operators in VBA. I'll leave this up for a while and anyone can feel free to drop some ideas in here and I'll test them.

Comment: Counting shouldn't be hard, question is how you want to manage it. But just incrementing the value in a cell would just be `range.value = range.value + 1` as long as the value in the cell is numeric or empty.

Comment: Don't bother toying with my suggestion I totally misunderstood what you wanted. Just use Christofer's suggestion.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber That's the solution I came to after some sleep. Figured it was something simple. Proper formatting, on the other hand, while not too terrible once you get over the initial shock of macro coding, is still strange. Got it handled though, I appreciate the tips everyone.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'll still check it out and poke around in it, but yes this was a simple problem with an easy answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub AddNewPage()

Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select 'references last sheet in workbook

Dim wks As Worksheet 'establish static variable wks to reference worksheets

Set wks = ActiveSheet 'set wks to be the defined active sheet





ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

Range("H9").Value = Range("H9").Value + 1 'sets value of cell H9 in new worksheets to sequentially increase by 1



If wks.Range("H9").Value <> "" Then

    On Error Resume Next

    wks = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select 'references last sheet in workbook

    ActiveSheet.Name = wks.Range("H9").Value + 1 'sets page title to sequentially increase by 1 with each iteration

End If

wks.Activate

End Sub
```

This is the solution I came up with with a little help from the internet. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: Just for future reference, and how exactly you write it is up to you, but `ActiveSheet.range().value` = `range`. What I mean by this is that if you just write a range, like `Range("A1")`, this is interpreted as `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value`. It's often useful to specify the sheet, to prevent unexpected behaviour, and Specifying value helps with readability, IMO. You'll get used to VBA.

Comment: I'll make a not of that and keep it in mind